# Eliminar de una tabla SQL registro de hace un año. DB2

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, db2

Desde mi aplicación en Java voy a controlar una sentencia SQL que consiste en eliminar los registros de una tabla de hace un año. La sentencia sería algo así:

```
DELETE FROM TABLA WHERE FECHA >= 1 año.
```

La columna FECHA de esa tabla es un char de 8 caracteres y estaría escrito de forma *"YYYYMMDD"*. He intentado utilizar una conversion a DATE y la funcion CURRENT DATE pero me sale lo siguiente:

```
1) [Code: -440, SQL State: 42884]  NO AUTHORIZED YEARS_BETWEEN NAMED  HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.22.29

2) [Code: -514, SQL State: 26501]  THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=4.22.29
```

¿Podrías echarme una mano para ver crear esa sentencia?

Muchas gracias

Un saludo.

Comment: Y cual fue el query que intentaste que tiro ese error? y si la fecha esta escrita como texto, porque no construis ese texto y haces la comparacion directamente?

Comment: y pq guardas la fecha como texto, guardala como fecha q para eso se invento ese tipo de dato